# How to insert data into 2 tables

Tags: json, sql-server, qsqlquery

I have table known as DepartmentDetails but i want to enter some the following data to another table.

Like in the case i have the NotificationId column inside the DepartmentDetails table but i want remove the NotificationId column from DepartmentDetails table and send them to a new table know as `DepartmentWiseNotification` and save NotificationId and DepartmentId in the `DepartmentWiseNotification`

I have a column called Id for both of the tables
How can i edit the following code but tried many ways but i failed,and im still a beginner.

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO DepartmentDetails
    (Code ,Name ,NotificationId, IsApplyForFO ,IsApplyForInv ,IsApplyForBan ,IsActive ,CreatedUserID ,LastModifiedUserID ,CreatedDate ,LastModifiedDate) 
    SELECT
    @Code ,@Name ,NotificationId,@IsApplyForFO ,@IsApplyForInv ,@IsApplyForBan ,@IsActive ,@CreatedUserID ,@LastModifiedUserID ,GETDATE() ,GETDATE()
    FROM OPENJSON(@DepartmentNotificationJSON)

    WITH
    (
        NotificationId INT '$.NotificationId'
    )

    END
    ELSE
```

Comment: Can you post the value of `@DepartmentNotificationJSON` variable?

Comment: @Zhorov Actually it comes from another table called notification and shows on the interface as checkboxes  eg-[Bar,Banquet,Kitchen] when the user clicks on the  notifications that he wants those values are passed in the Json

Comment: it's difficult without actual values for the variables, that are used in the statement. I'm not able to reproduce the issue without these values. Thanks.

Comment: @Zhorov In this case its Bar,Kitchen and Banquet

Comment: What does `SELECT @DepartmentNotificationJSON` return?

Comment: @Zhorov it returns its Bar,Kitchen and Banquet